# How to update my parsify() function such that it can go with local function along with global functions?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I have two functions namely **antiString()** and **parsify()** whose code is given below :

```
 function antiString(obj) {
    return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')();
 };

 function parsify(str) { 
     return str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ")
           .replace(/@--funs(.*?)--@/g, function(_, mat) { 
              return antiString(mat); 
            }); 
 };
```

Let's us consider a function something like :

```
 function ret(val) {
   return "I am " + val.toString()
 };
```

Now usage :

```
 var str = "Do you know who am I ? @--funs ret('Arcanadian') --@";
 console.log( parsify( str ) );
 // Output => Do you know whom am I ? I am Arcanadian
```

The code is beautiful but I have a problem with it ! This only works when the function inside the **@--funs** and **--@** is global. Thus if I have a lot of functions than I have to declare a lot of global functions. So I think I should move to local one ( since local therfore not chance of interaction with global, and by the way these functions would be specially designed for the **parsify()** so I think local is better, but also I will not remove the support for global ones, since rewriting the same global function code in the local one doesn't make any sense, but yes their determination syntax will be different. **@--lfuns** & **--@** will determine local functions while **@--gfuns** & **--@** will determine global functions ) but I can't understand how to do so ! But I can assume the new us of the **parsify()** function would be something like this :

```
 function q(val) {
   return "So " + val.toString();
 };

 var str = "@--lfuns name('Arc') --@. So @--gfuns q('can you help ?') --@";
 console.log( 
    parsify( str, {
      name: function(val) {
        return "I am " + val.toString();
      }
    })
 ); 

 // Output => I am Arc. So can you help ?
```

So, can you teach you where to update my code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you need the full power of `eval`, or are you just doing function calls with string arguments anyway?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I heard that eval has its own disadvantages !

Comment: It was also mentioned in the MDN documents.